# Writing empty string with quotes and NULL value without quotes while writing to csv in Python

Tags: python, mysql, export-to-csv

I am getting values from MySQL table that can be NULL values and empty strings.

However when I am trying to write these values into a csv file using `csv.writer(file_path, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)`, both NULL values and empty strings are written with quotes.

I would like the empty strings to be written with quotes and NULL values to be written without quotes.

Is there any way to achieve this in Python?